# Oracle xmltable query / ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton

Tags: oracle, xpath

I have this query :

```
SELECT   TYPE,  IDVIEW,  ATTRIBUTE,  VALUE
FROM XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('for $item in /SRDBSW/OBJ_DF[@IdView="ICU-ASW"]/*[@IdView] 
                          for $item_attr in $item/@*  
                          return element {$item/name(.)} 
                          {                     
                            element idview {$item/@IdView/string()},
                            element attr {$item_attr/local-name(.)},
                            element value {$item_attr/string()}
                          }
                          ' PASSING t.XMLDATA COLUMNS 
                          TYPE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)', 
                          IDVIEW VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'idview', 
                          attribute VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'attr', 
                          value VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'value' ) x
```

I´m getting this error :

> ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton
>   sequence - got multi-item sequence
>   19279. 00000 -  "XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence"

I found the problem , the problem is this line :

```
 element value {$item_attr/string()}
```

But can´t find a workaround to get the value of the attribute ...

where a sample off the xml

```
<OBJ_DF IdView="ICU-ASW" CategoryFlag="0" OwnerFlag="0" ObjLevel="Element" IsDefined="Y" ShortDescription="CONFIG Major function" ShortDescriptionCore="CONFIG Major function" LongDescription="CONFIG Major function Manual Load" Mnemonic="CONFIG Major function">
        <TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF IdView="0001" ShortDescription="PhysSide octet" ShortDescriptionCore="PhysSide octet" LongDescription="Type identifying the physical side of a unit in 8 bits" Mnemonic="Physical_Side_Octet_T" CategoryFlag="0" OwnerFlag="0" IsDirect="Y" Type="CURVE" CurveType="Textual" RawFormat="Unsigned Integer">
            <DIG_POINT_LIST>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="0" StatusText="SIDE_1" Mnemonic="Side_1" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Physical_Side_Octet.Side_1" HighValue="0"/>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="1" StatusText="SIDE_2" Mnemonic="Side_2" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Physical_Side_Octet.Side_2" HighValue="1"/>
            </DIG_POINT_LIST>
        </TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF>
        <TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF IdView="0002" ShortDescription="Health_T" ShortDescriptionCore="Health_T" LongDescription="Type for Health of unit or equipment" Mnemonic="Health_T" CategoryFlag="0" OwnerFlag="0" IsDirect="Y" Type="CURVE" CurveType="Textual" RawFormat="Unsigned Integer">
            <DIG_POINT_LIST>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="0" StatusText="UNHEALTHY" Mnemonic="Unhealthy" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Health.Unhealthy" HighValue="0"/>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="1" StatusText="HEALTHY" Mnemonic="Healthy" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Health.Healthy" HighValue="1"/>
            </DIG_POINT_LIST>
        </TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF>
        <TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF IdView="0003" ShortDescription="Logical_Power_T" ShortDescriptionCore="Logical_Power_T" LongDescription="Type for Logical On or Off status of unit or equipment" Mnemonic="Logical_Power_T" CategoryFlag="0" OwnerFlag="0" IsDirect="Y" Type="CURVE" CurveType="Textual" RawFormat="Unsigned Integer">
            <DIG_POINT_LIST>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="0" StatusText="OFF" Mnemonic="Off" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Logical_Power.Off" HighValue="0"/>
                <DIG_POINT LowValue="1" StatusText="ON" Mnemonic="On" Ldesc="FCI/Config/Logical_Power.On" HighValue="1"/>
            </DIG_POINT_LIST>
        </TEXTUAL_CURVE_DF>
    </OBJ_DF>
```

the query shoud return the name of the items and all is attribues

the working set is :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE directory XTDIR AS 'C:\Users\aadr\Documents\SCCOPEN\NEW-IMPORT\demo';


BEGIN
  DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.registerSchema(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename('XTDIR','SRDBSW_schema_full.xsd'));
END;

CREATE TABLE XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY (xmlkey VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, xmlData XMLType)
    xmltype column xmlData  XMLSCHEMA "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  element "SRDBSW" tablespace USERS;

   INSERT INTO XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY(XMLKEY, XMLDATA) VALUES 
   ('full',XMLType(bfilename('XTDIR', 'full.xml'), nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')));

   commit;
```

with all of this is not working , the reason I´m doing this is to increase preformace on the query whitout this the query is very slow whit large xmls files

Comment: Can you add a small sample XML document that generates the error?

Comment: It works fine for me (with an enclosing SRDBSW tag), in 11.2.0.3. What version are you running this under?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Can you try it with `element value {$item_attr[1]/string()}` - that is, with `[1]` added?

Comment: element value {$item_attr[1]/string()} , same error ORA-19279: XPTY0004 - XQuery dynamic type mismatch: expected singleton sequence - got multi-item sequence

Comment: other way to get this wihtout the 2 for´s ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bug 13060499, which is related to 7554407; see My Oracle Support doc ID 1373311.1. There isn't much info though. It's known to affect 11.2.0.2 but it isn't clear if or when it was fixed - I don't see the issue in 11.2.0.3 so it may have been quietly fixed in that patch set.

A workaround seems to be to add what should be a redundant index to the attribute reference:

```
element value {$item_attr[1]/string()}
```

But as that on its own doesn't seem to help, perhaps add it to everything:

```
SELECT   TYPE,  IDVIEW,  ATTRIBUTE,  VALUE
FROM XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('for $item in /SRDBSW/OBJ_DF[@IdView="ICU-ASW"]/*[@IdView] 
                          for $item_attr in $item[1]/@*  
                          return element {$item[1]/name(.)} 
                          {                     
                            element idview {$item[1]/@IdView[1]/string()},
                            element attr {$item_attr[1]/local-name(.)},
                            element value {$item_attr[1]/string()}
                          }
                          ' PASSING t.XMLDATA COLUMNS 
                          TYPE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)', 
                          IDVIEW VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'idview', 
                          attribute VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'attr', 
                          value VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'value' ) x;
```

In 11.2.0.3 that gives the same result as not having the node index. I don't have an 11.2.0.2 instance to verify it on though (and SQL Fiddle, which is that version, fails without a helpful message).

You can also do this with a single `for` in the XQuery, by going straight to attribute level and then referring to the parent node with `../`:

```
SELECT TYPE, IDVIEW, ATTRIBUTE, VALUE
FROM XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY t
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('for $item_attr in
    /SRDBSW/OBJ_DF[@IdView="ICU-ASW"]/*[@IdView]/@*
  return element {$item_attr[1]/../name(.)} 
  {                     
    element idview {$item_attr[1]/../@IdView[1]/string()},
    element attr {$item_attr[1]/local-name(.)},
    element value {$item_attr[1]/string()}
  }'
  PASSING t.XMLDATA
  COLUMNS 
    TYPE VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)', 
    IDVIEW VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'idview', 
    attribute VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'attr', 
    value VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'value' ) x;
```

I've left the `[1]` in just in case that is still helpful/needed. But SQL Fiddle now works [with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec445/11) and [without](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ec445/12) them, which is rather more promising.

Comment: If it's a bug that's been fixed then yes, and patching up to 11.2.0.3 or 11.2.0.4 (plus PSUs) isn't a bad idea anyway. The second query, with a single `for`, might work with what you have though. Maybe.

Comment: @AntónioRoque - what about the second query, with the single `for`?

Comment: some link to same sample .. to see what´s on your mind ?

Comment: its all must time to get out off office , can I get tomorrow "PLEASE" ?

Comment: @AntónioRoque - I have no idea what you are asking. I've given two queries to try. You said the first one doesn't work. You haven't said if you have tried the second one. I don't know what sample you mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.*  FROM XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY t 
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('/SRDBSW/OBJ_DF/*[/SRDBSW/OBJ_DF/@IdView="ICU-ASW"]' 
          PASSING t.XMLDATA   
          COLUMNS IdView VARCHAR2(30) PATH '@IdView', 
          attr_name VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)') x 
union   all        
SELECT z.* FROM XML_IMPORT_REPOSITORY tt 
CROSS JOIN XMLTABLE ('/SRDBSW/OBJ_DF/*[/SRDBSW/OBJ_DF/@IdView="ICU-ASW"]/@*' 
          PASSING tt.XMLDATA   
          COLUMNS  
          attr_name  VARCHAR2(30) PATH 'local-name(.)',
          attr_value VARCHAR2(30) PATH '.') z
```

this is all must good for me ... if I find a way ( if there is one ) to  separate "data" from the two query ...